# Receiving ID of instance CTreeCtrl again

Tags: c++, mfc

Is there any way in MFC to change or to learn ID of instance object like *CTreeCtrl.

In my project I have 3 equal bars with tree on each of them. Using pointer to bar I create bars and after Trees on these bars. I don't want to create own class for every bar. It will be bed solution.

So, after I want to use Tree's ID for making DDE. It will be very comfortable for me because class with trees containers already written. Thanks to DDE I will fast create  connection between CTreeCtrl and functional class.

I hope you have some ideas about this IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to create new class to accommodate each object.
I presume that you use Create member of the CTreeCtrl. Create takes ID as the last parameter. Use GetDlgCtrlID member to retrieve this ID.

GetDlgCtrlID is a member of CWnd and CTreeCtrl is derived from CWnd, hence it also inherits this function.